# SQL / PHP PDO Select random row

Tags: php, pdo

I want to be able to select a STUDENT randomly who has not FACED the exam ('N') and echo the name and subject. How can I achieve this?

```
$query = $db->prepare('SELECT name FROM exams WHERE faced = ?');
$array = array('N');
$query->execute($array);
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
$query = $db->prepare('SELECT name, subject
          FROM exams WHERE faced = ?
          ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1');
$array = array('N');
$query->execute($array);

$result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);

var_dump($result);
```

Comment: Just for the future: http://www.webtrenches.com/post.cfm/avoid-rand-in-mysql

Try to avoid using this method, and maybe try something from the following post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329396/mysql-select-10-random-rows-from-600k-rows-fast

Comment: Yes RAND() is a recipe for killing mysql server !!

Comment: If you have `INDEX(faced)` it won't be so bad.  Even better would be a "covering" `INDEX(faced, name, subject)`.