# Select Random query in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo

For several time I use to select random rows as:

```
$get_question = $user_home->runQuery('SELECT * FROM questions WHERE Level = :Level ORDER BY RAND()');
```

An expert told me that,

> RAND() is a recipe for killing MySQL server !!

So, with the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4329447/8995989) I tried:

```
$get_question = $user_home->runQuery('SELECT * FROM questions AS r1 JOIN (SELECT CEIL(RAND() * (SELECT MAX(Sr) FROM questions)) AS Sr) AS r2 WHERE r1.Sr >= r2.Sr AND Level = :Level ORDER BY r1.Sr ASC LIMIT 1');
```

And this is how I display the result:

```
echo $fetch_question['Question'] . "(" . $fetch_question['Id'] . ")";
```

And the display is:

```
question(id)
```

**But,** sometimes it displays only:

```
()
```

Why so? What is the mistake that I did?

[image: Here is the Snapshot of my database having question!!]

Comment: why dont you just fetch all rows and then select a random row per PHP?

Comment: @wayneOS I need only a single row per query, and here the database is having only 15 (5 per `Level`) for understanding, in realistic there 10K+ questions...

Comment: If using RAND() was not causing you any problems why change?

Comment: OP has mentioned `RAND() is a recipe for killing MySQL server !!`

Comment: And yet... if `Rand()` was working, why not use it? The advice from the "Expert" sounds questionable (but I'm not expert, just someone that would use Rand() if it were working for me.

Comment: @JNevill From my level/point of view, the user who [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21854184/sql-php-pdo-select-random-row#comment33082649_21854223) is well experienced!

Comment: `ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 11` -- takes milliseconds for a few thousand rows.  It takes seconds for a million rows.  OK, for a billion rows it is a "killer".  Do you have a billion rows?

Answer (score 0):

I think first of all you should know `max` and `min` id's of your table:

```
select max(id) as mx , min(id) as mn  from questions
```

then generate random id from **PHP:**

```
$randomId = rand($min, $max);
```

then run your query using this `$randomId`:

```
SELECT * FROM questions WHERE id = $randomId
```

**UPDATE:**

First of all get whole number of rows:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM questions
```

extract it into *PHP variable*, generate row number between zero and row number:

```
$randNum = rand(0, $rowCount);
```

and then run query like that:

```
SELECT * FROM questions LIMIT $rowNumber, 1
```

Comment: Equality comparison on ID only works if your records have no gaps.

Comment: OP has also [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50004039/select-random-query-in-mysql#comment87024852_50004039), that the table shown is just an example, and OP wants a **random question from a specific `Level`**. If the levels are jumbled it will be difficult to find out the `max` & `min` id.

Answer (score 0):

If you have under a million rows, `ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT nn` is not a "killer".

If you still decide that it is a killer, this has multiple ways to get a few random rows *without doing a full table scan*:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/random
(They go beyond godot's suggestions.)